# Query Entries based on current Entry's related Entries

Tags: craft3

I'm wanting to show related articles based on the current article's related Markets.

How do I get the current markets and filter relevant posts based on those related markets? This is what I have so far but doesn't seem correct.

```
{% set allMarkets = entry.relatedMarkets.all() %}
{% set currentID = entry.id %}

{# Get Related Articles Based on Markets #}
{% set expertBlog = craft.entries()
    .section('blog')
    .orderBy('postDate desc')
    .expertOpinion(true)
    .relatedMarkets([allMarkets])
    .id(['not', currentID])
    .limit(3) %}

      <h3 class="f3-l f3-xl fw5 mt0-l mt0-xl b tc">Enjoyed this article? Keep reading more expert insights...</h3>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap cf mb4 nl3-m nr3-m nl3-l nr3-l nl3-xl nr3-xl">
          {% cache %}
          {% for entry in expertBlog %}
              {% set columns = 'w-100 w-50-m w-33-l w-33-xl' %}
              {% include "_partials/lists/blog/_cards_blog_article_authors_expert.twig" %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endcache %}
      </div>
```

Comment: In your entry query, change ``.relatedMarkets([allMarkets])`` to ``.relatedTo(allMarkets)`` (use relatedTo instead and you don't need brackets).

Comment: Thanks if you post as an official answer I will accept.

Comment: Dan: You bet. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

In your entry query, change `.relatedMarkets([allMarkets])` to `.relatedTo(allMarkets)` (use [`relatedTo`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html) instead and you don't need array brackets).

Final code looks like:

```
{% set allMarkets = entry.relatedMarkets.all() %}
{% set currentID = entry.id %}

{% set expertBlog = craft.entries()
    .section('blog')
    .orderBy('postDate desc')
    .expertOpinion(true)
    .relatedTo(allMarkets)
    .id(['not', currentID])
    .limit(3)
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with entry counts. The trick was to get the ids from the first query and then use that as the sourceElement for the relatedTo query.

```
{% set userMugQuery = craft.entries().section('userMugs').relatedTo({targetElement: entry}) %}
{% set userMugAssetQuery = craft.assets()
    .volume('userAssets')
    .relatedTo({ sourceElement: userMugQuery.ids(), field: 'userAssets' })
%}
{% set userMugCount = userMugQuery.count() %}
{% set userMugAssetCount = userMugAssetQuery.count() %}
```